# Centos Linux Self Contained (SCD) ASP.NET Core Application startup exception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, centos7, sigabrt

Hello to all my heros :) I am new to Linux. I created an .net core web application using identity. I want to publish self contained. I installed all required linux librarys. Gave the filesystem permissions. On my local virtual machine it runs. But on my digitalocaen droplet it doesnt. :( Please help me.

This is the console output when I call the executable.

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
>   Application startup exception: System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[cihanturan.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationUser, cihanturan.WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' for the parameter 'userManager' of method 'Configure' on type 'cihanturan.WebUI.Startup'. ---> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 84.
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 mySqlOptionsAction)
>      at cihanturan.WebUI.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\Cihan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\cihanturan\cihanturan.WebUI\Startup.cs:line 38
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception...........

This is Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)    
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }   

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCihanConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCihanConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>   
        {  
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail =true;                               

            options.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;

        })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Admin/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Name = "CookieCihan";
            options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Account/Login";                      

        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/Index", "?statusCode={0}");   
        app.UseStaticFiles();               
        app.UseAuthentication();   
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>        
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        MyIdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager,app);

    }
}
```

This is Program.cs

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }


        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options=>options.ValidateScopes=false);
    }
```

Comment: What is your asp.net core version? For `services.AddIdentity`, it will register required service. Which runtime did you install on Centos?

Comment: One more note, what is your connectionstring. Try to check whether the connection strhing is valid and is accessable.

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to inject UserManager into Configure Method which is not yet registered into the services.

as a result, your application cannot resolve `UserManager`